# How do you add elements to a List<T extends I1 & I2>?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble using generics effectively. Most of the time when I encounter the problem described below I end up finding another way to accomplish what I need, but it leaves me with the feeling that I lack some understanding surrounding the usage of generics in Java.

If I wanted to create a method that would return a List, where T extends anything I get a compiler error saying that whatever I add to the list cannot be converted to T.

Please see the code below for example(s):

```java
public interface I1 {
}

public interface I2 {
}

public class ValidType implements I1, I2 {
}

public class OtherValidType extends ValidType {
}

public class Foo {
    private static <T extends I1 & I2> List<T> getList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ValidType());
        list.add(new OtherValidType());
        return list;
    }
}
```

The compiler won't even let me do something more simple such as:

```java
public class Foo {
    private static <T extends ValidType> List<T> getList() {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ValidType());
        return list;
    }
}
```

I know in the second example I could just do a List and classes inheriting that type would be accepted, this is just for the sake of trying to understand where I'm going wrong with my understanding of Generics.

All of the above yield a compilation error "add(T) in List cannot be applied to (ValidType)" for example.

Where am I misunderstanding the usage of generics as return types/Type parameters?

Answer (score 4):

How do you know that `T` in both examples is a superclass of `ValidType` or `OtherValidType`?

`T` could be some entirely different class that also happens to implement interfaces `I1` and `I2`, in which case you cannot put instances of `ValidType` and `OtherValidType` in it.

For your second example, try:

```
List<OtherValidType> list = Foo.getList();
```

It should be clear that `T` is `OtherValidType`, but yet you're trying to insert a `ValidType` in it, but `ValidType` isn't a subclass of `OtherValidType` (its it's superclass).

There are cases where you could make use of the construct, for example:

```
private static <T extends I1 & I2> List<T> getList(T a, T b) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    return list;
}
```

but if you don't know what type `T` is, you can't ever know whether the concrete known classes `ValidType` and `OtherValidType` are assignable to it.

Comment: You can cast it to type `T` like `list.add((T) new ValidType());`. But it's a `unchecked` cast. This is the perfect answer.

Comment: @SachithDickwella also a cast to a type is not enforced by the compiler in any shape or form

Answer (score 0):

For this method:

```
private static <T extends ValidType> List<T> getList() {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ValidType());
    return list;
}
```

it's like you would declare (if it would have been possible):

```
List<T extends ValidaType> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The only thing you can put to such a `List` would be a `T`; though the language does not allow this declaration. On the other hand the language does allow declaring something like this, using a so called *wildcard* (using it here just to prove a point):

```
List<? extends ValidType> list = new ArrayList<>();
ValidType vt = list.get(0);
```

You still can't put anything (you can `null`, but that is not the point), but when you *retrieve* something from that `List` - you can only get a `ValidType` and that is the enforcement you get. You can put any subtypes (as `T`) into it, but you can retrieve only the super-type, because you don't really know what sub-types were put in there. Thus your method:

```
private static <T extends ValidType> List<T> getList() {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    return list;
}
```

will be enforced when called:

```
List<OtherValidType> l1 = getList(); // compiles
List<String> l2 = getList(); // does not compile
```